# Where am I missing an IP address in the connection string of my web application?

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, database-connection

Ok,
First of all, I want to make the disclaimer that aside from some HTML I have done very little programming in my lifetime.  However, as necessity so often dictates, I am in dire need of some assistance with that very thing at this moment.

Our agency has a web site that is hosted by another entity, and that entity is forcing our hand in moving the content of that site onto one of our own servers. All content has been moved to the new server, and all database tables from the old database have been moved onto our internal SQL server.  The site primarily consists of asp files, but there is one page that is aspx.  The problem arises when taking the "old" database tables offline and testing the aspx page.  Even though all instances of the IP address to the old SQL server have been changed to reflect the IP of the new SQL server, the aspx page insists on requiring the connection to the old database (the error indicates the tables are offline, thus pointing to the old SQL server). Everything else works as it should, and the "Web Application" has been designated as such in IIS.

I know I am missing something somewhere... but I just can't put my finger on it.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I'm starting to wonder if the reference to the old IP address is compiled in a file somewhere that I just can't find.

Thanks

Comment: if the connection string is set in the code behind file and not in the web config file thy will be in the application dll. mybe thats the problem. do you still have the project ?

Comment: If the site is a website and not an application compiled into a dll, you might be able to see the code for that aspx page.Check to see if the old server name is in that code page.It will have an extension aspx.cs or aspx.vb. Another possibility is to right click the aspx page and see the source.

Comment: Search the code for the old IP as well as the name of the old server.

Comment: It is indeed an aspx.vb web application, and I'm pretty sure the original programmer just used WebApplication1 as its name since that's the name of the directory.  I have a WebApplication1.vbproj file that lists  all of the original files in the project when opened in VS2010, including the one that is not working, and there is a WebApplication1.dll in the bin directory.  All readily apparent IP address instances have been changed in every file within the site to reflect the new SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found my solution.  For programmers, this solution probably would have been a no-brainer, but for others maybe not so much.

I have to give a pat on the back to "Creator" for pointing me in the direction of the project file.  I wasn't sure that it was still available, but thankfully the programmer who designed this application somewhere a little over ten years ago was nice enough to leave it in the web directory with everything else.

What I wound up doing was as follows:

1. Opened the project file in Visual Studio 2010 and converted the project from 2003 to 2010.
2. Added the connection strings into the web.config to the new SQL server.
3. Right clicked on each item and excluded all of the old pieces to the application (in Solution Explorer) that were no longer needed.
4. Right clicked on the project and navigated to Package/Publish Settings > Package/Publish SQL and chose to "Import from Web.config".
5. Saved the project, then right clicked and "Converted to Web Application".
6. Right clicked and performed a "Build".  I'm guessing this re-wrote the dll file.
7. Copied the directory and needed files back over to the web server and converted the directory in IIS to a Web Application.
8. Sat back and marveled at my success.

Thank you guys for pointing me the right direction!